# Error java.lang.NumberFormatException al convertir String a int

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa que lea lo que hay en un txt y lo pase al java para después hacer otras cosas con eso.

El txt es el siguiente(tiene un saldo de linea al principio y dos al final):

> InformacionDelSistema.txt:26:Memoria física disponible:                 2.905 MB

Guardo todo ese texto es el String memoriaLibre, después para sacar el numero uso substring(), para cortarlo justo donde está, luego le quito el punto con replace(".", "") y por ultimo uso trim() para quitarle los espacio que pudiera tener al principio o al final, y todo eso lo guardo en el String memoriaLibreCortada.

El error aparece cuando intento convertir memoriaLibreCortada a un int, mi pregunta es: porque aparece este error sabiendo que memoriaLibreCortada si es un numero? (tambien intenté convertirlo con valueOf())

El error que aparece es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2905"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at com.mycompany.graficadora.ObtenerMemoria.leer(ObtenerMemoria.java:78)
    at com.mycompany.graficadora.Graficadora.main(Graficadora.java:75)
```

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ObtenerMemoria {

    public void leer() {

        String memoriaLibre = "";


        try {

            FileReader archivo = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\YEISON\\Downloads\\MemoriaLibre.txt");


            int memoria = archivo.read();

            while (memoria != -1) {
                memoria = archivo.read();

                //Al convertirlo a char lo estamos convirtiendo en codigo ASII
                char memoriaChar = (char) memoria;

                //Lo agrega al string
                memoriaLibre += memoriaChar;
            }


            String memoriaLibreCortada = memoriaLibre.substring(149, 158);



            memoriaLibreCortada = memoriaLibreCortada.replace(".", "");


            //Esto quita los espacios que hayan al principio o al final
            memoriaLibreCortada.trim();


            /*AQUÍ HAY UN ERROR, NO CONVIERTE CORRECTAMENTE*/
            int memoriaRam = Integer.parseInt(memoriaLibreCortada);


            archivo.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: No tendrás un espacio en la cadena? Hace un `System.out.println(memoriaLibreCortada.length());` justo antes de parsear, para el número que se muestra en el error, el 2905, debe dar `4`

Comment: Dice que el tamaño es 8, no sé porqué. Si al primer argumento de substring le sumo uno, sale 905 y si le resto uno al segundo sale 290.

Comment: Bueno, checkea eso, ya vas flanqueando el error, también imprimí la cadena para ver los caracteres `System.out.println(memoriaLibreCortada);`

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces esto `memoriaLibre.substring(149, 158)` se te podría caer en cuanto la cadena de texto sea de diferente tamaño.

Lo mejor que podrías hacer es extraer el número con una expresión regular. Por ejemplo con un método al que le pases el String y te devuelva el double. Algo así:

```
public double parsearMemoriaLibre(String texto) throws Exception {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?\\s(GB|MB|KB)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

    if(matcher.find()) {
        String memoriaLibre = matcher.group().substring(0, matcher.group().length() - 3);
        return Double.parseDouble(memoriaLibre);
    }

    throw new Exception("El texto no contiene un tamaño de memoria libre.");
}
```

De esta manera no importa el tamaño del texto, te va a extraer el número en tanto siga el formato `123.456 MB` o `GB` o `KB` o te lanzará una excepción si no pudo extraer el dato.

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que al leer el txt se agregaban espacios vacíos entre los números.
En vez de guardar 2.905, guardaba 2_._9_0_5, entonces lo que hice para que funcionara fue eliminar estos espacios, hice un ciclo y usé charAt(entero) para verificar que lo que guardara fuera un numero.